# Node JS memory leak when making lots of HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I am trying to run the following node script:

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');
var util = require('util');


function makeRequest(dom, cb) {
    request("http://" + dom,
            function(err, response, body) {
                console.log(util.inspect(process.memoryUsage()));
                cb();
            });
}

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1600000; i++) {
    arr.push("google.com");
}

async.eachLimit(arr, 100, function(dom, call) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        makeRequest(dom, call);
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log("done");
});

function call() {

}
```

I'm basically making **a lot** of HTTP requests to a web service (I used *google.com* for example's sake). The problem is the script's memory usage just steadily increases without backing down up until the point it crashes with a "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory". Can anyone please tell me why the memory leak occurs and how I can fix it? Thank you.

Comment: This problem seems to be similar to yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927377/node-js-fatal-error-js-allocation-failed-process-out-of-memory-while-parsin

Comment: Yes, I know about that post. I tried increasing the memory limit and I get the same error. Also, using more than 2GBs or RAM is not an option for me...

Comment: @Nightfall did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem: with eachLimit making http requests.

Comment: No, i dropped it. But i guess you could eventually split the array into smaller sub-arrays, write each in a separate file and run the script on each of them (in case you are reading the initial array contents from a file, database or something similar).

Comment: I just in the same situation, any solution??